# Highlight matched text instead of the whole the text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function, `getTextNodes`, that searches text nodes recursively. Then I use a `addHighlight` function to highlight the text with `<mark>` tags:

```js
const buttonEl = `<button>
  <span>
    Icon
  </span>
  Text
</button>
`;

document.body.innerHTML = buttonEl;

const foundButtonEl = document.querySelector("button");
const elements = [];

elements.push(foundButtonEl);

addHighlight(elements, "T");

function addHighlight(elements, text) {
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    const textNodes = getTextNodes(document.body);
    const matchingNode = textNodes.find(node => node.textContent.includes(text));

    const markElement = document.createElement('mark');
    markElement.innerHTML = matchingNode.textContent;
    matchingNode.replaceWith(markElement);
  });
}

function getTextNodes(node) {
  let textNodes = [];

  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    textNodes.push(node);
  }

  node.childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
    textNodes.push(...getTextNodes(childNode));
  });

  return textNodes;
}
```

The problem is that `addHighlight` is highlighing the whole text (in the example, `Text`), instead of the matched text (in the example, `T`).

How to change this code so that only the matched text is highlighted (`text`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matchingNode` is the whole node so you're replacing everything. If you want to match just part of it, you need to iterate though the textnode and find the index position of the substring that you're searching for.

Start by splitting the node into an array

```
matchingNode.wholeText.split("")
```

Then find the index position, insert `markElement` at that position, and go from there.

Comment: I think you can split a textNode: `Uncaught TypeError: matchingNode.split is not a function`

Comment: @alexchenco My bad, do this for the text node matchingNode.wholeText.split("")

Comment: How would you get the index of, for example, `Te` (two words)? Could you provide an example?

Comment: This should help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-an-array-is-subarray-of-another-array/. First turn 'text' into an array e.g. ["T", "e"] then find it in the larger array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the node you match is the element of which the innerContent contains the string you want to highlight.

What you should do instead of :

```
markElement.innerHTML = matchingNode.textContent;
matchingNode.replaceWith(markElement);
```

is probably something like

```
markElement.innerHTML = text;
matchingNode.replaceTextWithHTML(text, markElement);
```

replaceTextWithHTML is a fictive function :)